# Initialize GUID in with value in {745a17a0-74d3-11d0-b6fe-00a0c90f57da} format

Tags: c++

I need to initialize a GUID variable to a  particular value. This is ClassGuid variable which has fixed values which are [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553426(v=vs.85).aspx). As can be seen on the linked page these values are in {x-x-x-x} format, how do I initialize my variable with these?

```
GUID InterfaceClassGuid = {745a17a0-74d3-11d0-b6fe-00a0c90f57da} // doesn't compile
```

Answer (score 2):

That's just the conventional human-readable notation, not valid C++ syntax.

A `GUID` is a wrapper for a *number*, and [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) tells you how Microsoft allows you to set it.

In particular, they provide [a constructor that takes a string in various formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1); for example:

```
 GUID InterfaceClassGuid("745a17a0-74d3-11d0-b6fe-00a0c90f57da");
```

Comment: It doesn't compile. error: `C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [37]' to 'GUID'
No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous`

Comment: @zadane: Read the documentation to find out what to pass. I have no idea how your program is structured or what technologies you're using, as you didn't say. A very quick Google search reveals [`GUIDFromString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776431(v=vs.85).aspx), which may be of relevant here.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about GUID object but what you're giving is not a valid value, it seems that it should be either a string,

```
{ "745a17a0-74d3-11d0-b6fe-00a0c90f57da" }
```

or a hex value,

```
{ 0x745a17a0, 0x74d3, 0x11d0, 0xb6fe, 0x00a0c90f57da }
```

Sharing the compilation error would help, though.